# jquery ui dialog with ajax on return data forbidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a problem with my jquery ui dialog box. When I genereate the dialog event I get as error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /<!DOCTYPE on this server.
```

my code

```
    // Init Dialog Texte
   $('a.open_dialog_texte').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/texte/texte.php?id=3",
            //data: string,
            success: function(data) {
                 $('<div />').appendTo('body').load(data).dialog({    
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    width: 800,
                    position: 'top'   
                    });     
                 }
         });
       return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` obviously isn't a url, you'll want to append it, not ajax load it...

```
$('<div />').appendTo('body').html(data).dialog({
```